# home page background color change after login

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a website https://www.gotravelsglobal.com/travel.
before login the website is like below image
[image]

But after login to that website My website background color is auto changed like below image
[image]

Can't find where is the problem. Is there any script related issue ?

Anybody help please ? Thanks in advance

demo login info

email : test@gmail.com

password : test

Comment: ur url is not working
and check the console if there is any error

Comment: It is always dubious to ask users to login to a third party website. If you have an issue you should post your details here along with the problem code.

Comment: Have you set different background images for the login page and the logged in pages? Check your page CSS if you can't find it in a script.

Comment: Share the Html pages code and the CSS linked to each of them to make the question better.

Comment: So many details are missing in this question.The important part is the markup of login and landing page.

Comment: If you are the site developer you should know that these changes can originate from the server side, so what you have posted here won't help you in any way with your site's problem - even with the login details. Except you are trying to hack to site.

Comment: @ sayalok....sorry for the mistake now url is working. I have already check the console

Comment: @ScottieG....no brother....same background...but from where it is changed can't find

Comment: There is an issue with your HTML structure after logging in.

If you inspect using chrome dev tools and find the div with id "#top-bar".

After logging in, your whole content is wrapped inside this "#top-bar" div.

Comment: Your top bar's (i mean header) background is what you see as the background for the whole content.

Comment: @ DreamTeK...Your are absolutely right. It's a lots of files of css, scripts and html pages of one of my official project. As a beginner I can't understand that for which css or script file this changes occurs...that's why i am asking like that...Sorry for that

Comment: 2xSamurai....I find that there is a problem with the div id  "#top-bar" as you told. After successfully logging in with ajax I have used `location.reload(true);` to relaod the current page. Is the problem with this `location.reload(true);` ? What do you think brother ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Are you adding any HTML content or altering anything after sign in? In the header section?

Comment: @ 2xSamurai....solved Brother !!! One of my div is misplaced while perform logging in function.....Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help. (:

Answer (score 1):

As you can see after logging in as the test user. There seems to be some problem with HTML structure which causes your content to be placed inside your header(which is blue in color). Making it feel that your content background has changed. In fact, your content is being placed inside your header.

Please check your code where you do the sign in process.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of html structure. See the below screenshot.

```
<div id="top-bar" class="tb-text-white">
```

[image]

Div should be close properly similar as below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: ...Solved !! One of my `div` is misplaced while perform logging in function in html. I have got the idea after seeing your two photos. Thanks a lot brother